# Order a list of entities based on a field from a separate entity with a relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm using Entity Framework for my object-relational mapping, and jqGrid for my grid.

I have an **Employee** entity, that contains a ContactID field. I have a **Contact** entity that contains fields FirstName and LastName.

I want to display a list of Employees in a grid, and give the user the ability to sort by FirstName and LastName.

Here's what I have right now:

```
public JsonResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    var pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    var pageSize = rows;
    var totalRecords = GetAllEmployees().Count();
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

    IQueryable<Employee> employees = GetAllEmployees().
                                          OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).
                                          Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).
                                          Take(pageSize).ToArray();

    ...
}
```

As you can see, this only gives me the ability to sort by fields in the Employee entity, so I can't sort by FirstName and LastName.

How can I modify this to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other option you would have to use a projection that includes those fields, it could be something like:

```
GetAllEmployees()
.Select( e => new { 
                    Person = e, 
                    Contact = Contacts.Where( c=> c.Id == e.ContactID).Single() 
                  })
.OrderBy( x => x.Contact.LastName)
.Select( x => x.Person) //back to Employee
.Skip(...)
.Take(...)
```

This is not terribly efficient, since you'd have to query the `Contacts` entity set for each employee (so n queries!) - so I'd suggest modifying the initial Linq to Entities query to return you a list of Employees with their associated contact, which can be done with a join, i.e. `GetEmployeesWithContact()`

The best Linq to Entities style solution would be to [include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) the Contacts when you load the Employees:

```
var emps = Employees.Include("Contact");
```

now each Employee in `emps` will have a `Contact` Property that you can use in your projection:

```
IQueryable<Employee> employees = emps.OrderBy(x=> x.Contact.LastName)
                                     .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).
                                     .Take(pageSize).ToArray();
```